# Random numbers within a range, but close to the last generated number

Tags: c#, random, range

I have some code which generates random numbers for my ints within a range, but i also want to implement it so that when it generates the next number, it cannot be greater than 3 either side of previously generates number.

So for example if my rbp gets a value of 140 generated, the next would be between 137&143.

Not sure how i would go about implementing this?

```
timer1.Interval = 1000;
Random r = new Random();
int rbp = r.Next(89, 260);//BP
int rhr = r.Next(39, 131);//HR
int rrr = r.Next(8, 25);//RR
int ros = r.Next(90, 120);//OS
double rtemp = r.Next(34, 40);//Temp
```

Comment: Im not sure what you mean, are you saying that the randomly generated number can never = less than the first range? It seems to be working fine so far.

Comment: Never mind, thought you meant something else.

Comment: So you're saying you want to generate a random number from -3 to +3 and add that to the previous number?

Answer (score 2):

Say you take your variable `rbp`:

```
int rbp = r.Next(89,260);
```

the next time you generate `rbp`, you would base the range on the value of `rbp`:

```
rbp = r.Next(rbp - 3 < 89 ? 89 : rbp - 3, rbp + 3 > 260 ? 260 : rbp + 3);
```

Here, I ensure that the range will never go below 89 or above 260.

Example:

```
Random r = new Random();
int rbp = r.Next(89, 260);
Console.WriteLine(rbp);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    rbp = r.Next(rbp - 3 < 89 ? 89 : rbp - 3, rbp + 3 > 260 ? 260 : rbp + 3);
    Console.WriteLine(rbp);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: guessing its an error where you have written rpb instead of rbp, but when i try this im getting a message saying unassigned local variable rbp

Comment: You are correct, that was a typo. This code is based upon the second time that `rbp` is being created. If you try to use this for the first time you generate `rbp`, you will get an error since `rbp` has yet to be defined. I will update to clarify.

Comment: Testing this it seems that its not working as intended, the next generated value can still have a large leap

Comment: Then there is an error in your implementation. I added an example that I verified to be working correctly.

Comment: @cantcodeforcookie - The example code will give a list of 11 answers with small jumps. A next set of 11 will start anywhere, unless you remember the last value of the previous set and work from there.